# Replace content between two tags

Tags: php, replace, preg-replace

I want to replace all content between `(` and `)`, using php.

my string:

```
$string = "This is a (string)";
```

the required output is:

```
$string = "This is a";
```

my code doesn't works:

```
$string = "This is a (string)";
$search = "/[^(](.*)[^)]/";
$string = preg_replace($search, "", $string);
echo $string;  // output is ")"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$result = preg_replace('/\(.+?\)/sm', 'Put your text here', $string);
```

Try this code

Or to save () add them to replacement

```
$page = preg_replace('/\(.+?\)/sm', '(Put your text here)', $page);
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $string = "This is a (string)";
    echo preg_replace("/\([^)]+\)/","",$string);

?>
```

Output:

```
This is a
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change that:

```
$search = "/ *\(.*?\)/";
```